# Conditionally add to resource attribute via terraform

Tags: azure, terraform

i am attempting to create a service fabric cluster via terraform, I wish to add either 1 or 2 node type parameters dynamically.

My cluster is defined as so:

```
resource "azurerm_service_fabric_cluster" "example" {
  name                 = "example-servicefabric"
  resource_group_name  = "${var.cluster_name}-group"
  location             = var.location
  reliability_level    = "Bronze"
  upgrade_mode         = "Manual"
  cluster_code_version = "7.1.456.959"
  vm_image             = "Windows"
  management_endpoint  = "https://example:80"

  node_type{
        name                 = "first"
        instance_count       = 3
        is_primary           = true
        client_endpoint_port = 2020
        http_endpoint_port   = 80
  }

    node_type{
        name                 = "second"
        instance_count       = 3
        is_primary           = true
        client_endpoint_port = 2020
        http_endpoint_port   = 80
  }
}
```

What I would like, is to deploy only the 'first' node_type when a variable is false, and deploy both 'first' and 'second' when a variable is true.

Usually, If i was deploying resources, I would use

```
  count                = var.node_type_count > 1 ? 1 : 0
```

However this cannot be done as the node types themselves are not resources, they are simply attributes. How can i conditionally add to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [dynamic blocks](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks.html). Basically, `first` is always created, while `second` is optional:

```
resource "azurerm_service_fabric_cluster" "example" {
  name                 = "example-servicefabric"
  resource_group_name  = "${var.cluster_name}-group"
  location             = var.location
  reliability_level    = "Bronze"
  upgrade_mode         = "Manual"
  cluster_code_version = "7.1.456.959"
  vm_image             = "Windows"
  management_endpoint  = "https://example:80"


  node_type {
        name                 = "first"
        instance_count       = 3
        is_primary           = true
        client_endpoint_port = 2020
        http_endpoint_port   = 80    
  }

  dynamic "node_type" {

    for_each = var.second_node == true ? [1] : []

    content {
        name                 = "second"
        instance_count       = 3
        is_primary           = true
        client_endpoint_port = 2020
        http_endpoint_port   = 80    
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: This works - Could you please specify what the purpose of the [1] is for? Shouldn't this be [0] As we are are trying to access the first value? i.e. we only have 1 dynamic node type

Comment: @MantyQuestions It can be any value, as you are not using it. This is just to have one iteration of `for_each`.